# After deleting a partition, iMac will only boot to a grey screen -- how do I fix this?

Tags: imac

I was deleting a partition when my iMac froze and rebooted itself. Now I can't get any further during boot than a grey screen.

Things I have tried to fix this include:

- Booting with CMD-R (boots to a grey screen)
- Resetting the PRAM (boots to a grey screen)
- Resetting SMC (boots to a grey screen)
- Booted in target disk mode and repaired the disk. Disk repair was successful but a reboot booted to a grey screen
- Attempted to boot from an install disk but all I get is the grey screen
- Attempted to boot in Safe Mode. This gets about half way and then fails.
- CMD-V on boot shows last posted messages as: `SMCREADKEYACTION ERROR SMCREADDATA 8 FAILED`

Do you think the hard drive is done even though Disk Utility said it was okay? Or is something else wrong with it?

This is a 2006 iMac 6.1.

Comment: The formatting and information here make this question hard to decipher. I took a stab at cleaning it up but it's hard to tell what some of your actions taken actually are. Please review my edit. Also, drop the ALL CAPS for future posts please. For help on using Markdown to format your question see [Markdown help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help). For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63848/what-can-be-done-to-fix-a-2011-imac-that-will-not-boot-past-the-white-screen?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131592/imac-will-not-boot?rq=1

Comment: Explain Attempted to boot from install disk- failed ? You obviously have done something to the boot sector, so it needs to be recreated, assuming there is no screwed up partitioning.

Comment: when i try to boot from install disk i get grey screen spinning wheel then .full grey screen. how do i fix boot sector?